# What's special about \: in the implementation of \pgfutil@ifnextchar

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

There is the following snippet of code in `pgfutil-common.tex` (with a very
similar snippet in pgfmathutil.code.tex`):

```
{%
  \def\:{\global\let\pgfutil@sptoken= } \:
  \def\:{\pgfutil@xifnch} \expandafter\gdef\: {\futurelet\pgfutil@let@token\pgfutil@ifnch}
}
```

I've been trying to understand this by means of writing my own version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter

\newcommand\aetest{\ae@test}
\def\ae@test(#1){%%
  \textsf{#1}%%
  \ae@ifnextchar H%%
  {\ae@true}{\ae@false}}

\def\ae@true#1;{ \textbf{(true):#1}}
\def\ae@false#1;{ \textbf{(false):#1}}

\long\def\ae@ifnextchar#1#2#3{%%
  \let\ae@reserved@d=#1%%
  \def\ae@reserved@a{#2}%%
  \def\ae@reserved@b{#3}%%
  \futurelet\ae@let@token\ae@ifnch}
\def\ae@ifnch{%%
  \ifx\ae@let@token\ae@sptoken
    \let\ae@reserved@c\ae@xifnch
  \else
    \ifx\ae@let@token\ae@reserved@d
      \let\ae@reserved@c\ae@reserved@a
    \else
      \let\ae@reserved@c\ae@reserved@b
    \fi
  \fi
  \ae@reserved@c}
{%%
  \def\:{\global\let\ae@sptoken= } \: 
  \def\:{\ae@xifnch} \expandafter\gdef\: {\futurelet\ae@let@token\ae@ifnch}%%
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\aetest(This test is) Hello;

\aetest(This test is) Ciao;

\end{document}
```

The above code compiles correctly and as expected.

The mentioned snippet has been rewritten as:

```
{%%
  \def\:{\global\let\ae@sptoken= } \: 
  \def\:{\ae@xifnch} \expandafter\gdef\: {\futurelet\ae@let@token\ae@ifnch}%%
}
```

I believe I understand what this snippet is supposed to do:

(a) `\let` the token `\ae@sptoken` to a space token

(b) Scan ahead over any space token in the token list to the next non-space token.

I have two questions:

(1) Why the need to use `\:` instead of some other control sequence?

(2) Why isn't the space following `\expandafter\gdef\:` eaten after expansion?

On page 39 of The TeXBook, Knuth writes:

> .... spaces are not ignored after control sequences inside a token list; the
>   ignore-space rule applies only in an input file, during the time that strings of
>   characters are being tokenized.

Because of this, I thought I could rewrite the first line of this snippet as:

```
\def\ae@colon{\global\let\ae@sptoekn= }\ae@colon
```

I was under the impression that, since the space after the equal sign has
already been tokenized, it wouldn't be lost.  But what seems to be happening is
that when `\ae@colon` is expanded, this tokenized space is irrelevant.  Instead,
`\ae@sptoken` is `\let` to `\def`.  Though I'm not sure how to verify this or
not, LaTeX just complains that `\ae@xifnch` is undefined.  Hence my first question.

Regarding `\expandafter\gdef\:` and the following space:  I was thinking that
this space should be lost since `\:` is expanded before the space is tokenized.
Therefore I thought one of the following might work:

```
\expandafter\gdef\:{....} %%<-- no space following "\:"
```

or

```
\gdef\ae@xifnch{....}
```

or

```
\gdef\ae@xifnch {...} %%<-- space after \ae@xifnch
```

But neither work.  Instead, LaTeX hangs.  I assume that's because it keeps
parsing the same space token and is unable to remove it from the list.

So somehow when `\expandafter\gdef\:` is expanded, the following space is
preserved.  Hence my second question.

Regarding the choice of a colon, I know there's nothing special with `\:`.  I've
experimented with `\!` and `\,`.  Both work perfectly fine.  So, the trick here
has something to do with how control symbols (control sequence consisting of one
non-letter) work.  But, I'm somehow missing how `\:` is achieving the desired
effect here.

Comment: (Not verified, but the first point to observe). There is a space in the definition of `\gdef\: `. If we use name other than one non-letter, a space is ignored, because it only terminates the name.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke That's one of the points that baffles me.  But there is no command name here with a space in its name.  There is just a space following `\expandafter\gdef\:*` where by `*` I'm referring to the space.

Comment: Not a space in a name, but a space, which must appear after the name. (In the other case the usage doesn't match the definition.)

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke OK I see your point there.  But by applying `\expandafter`, why are `\expandafter\gdef\:*{...}` and \gdef\ae@xifnch*{...}` not equivalent?  Shouldn't that space still be getting eaten?

Comment: @Manuel I'm thinking that `\expandafter\gdef\:*` expands to `\gdef\ae@xifnch*` which would consequently ignore that space since it's no longer following a single non-letter token.

Comment: Note that the code here is more-or-less the same as setting up the space-skipping for `\@ifnextchar` in `latex.ltx` (`pgf` works without LaTeX so needs its own version here).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I now understand what's happening here.

The syntax for `\let` is as follows

```
\let<control sequence><equal><one optional space><token>
```

If I write, where `*` indicates a space

```
\let\ae@sptoken=*
```

then `*` is just interpreted as the `<one optional space>` and the next token is grabbed for the `\let`ting.

In the case of `\def\:{\let\ae@sptoken= }`, the space following the `=` is the `<one optional space>`.  Now since `\:` is a command symbol, the space following it will be converted into a space token.  Given that when LaTeX reaches the end of the line it converts the end of line character into a space (provided LaTeX is in state `M`).  That means that

```
\:
```

expands to

```
\let\ae@sptoken=**
```

(again I'm using `*` to indicate the space).  And so `\ae@sptoken` is `\let` to a space.

A similar effect can be achieved by:

```
\def\ae@colon{\let\ae@sptoken= }
\expandafter\ae@colon\space
```

The trick here is in finding a way to smuggle in two adjacent spaces immediately following the `=`.

Regarding

```
\expandafter\gdef\: {....}
```

I misunderstood when spaces are converted into tokens.  The conversion happens prior to the expansion of `\expandafter`.  Thus when the above line is expanded it becomes

```
\gdef\ae@xifnch*{....}
```

where `*` is for the space which, now that it's a token, will not be gobbled by the command string.

A similar effect can be achieve by:

```
\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\ae@sptoken\space{....}
```

Comment: Note that this is a straighforward copy from lines 813-814 of `latex.ltx`, apart from the group around the definitions and the \global that are thus required. The LaTeX kernel uses a “real space”, instead of relying on the end-of-line conversion.